# Having a bad output in Arduino program

Tags: c, arduino

i have a problem with this Arduino  program
Here is my code

```
char *stringsplit(char msg[])
 
{
  char *words[4];
   char * p;
  int i = 0;
   char dauphay[] = ",";
  p = strtok(msg, dauphay);
 while(p && i < 4)
  {
    words[i] = p;
    p = strtok(NULL, dauphay);
    ++i;
  }
  return *words;
}
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);
  char msg[]="first,Second,third,four";
  char *p1=stringsplit(msg);
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  {
    Serial.println(p1[i]);
  }
}
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

My expected output is "First Second Third Four"
But my real output is "F i r s"
What should i do to fix this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `stringsplit()`, you return `*words`. This is the same as

```
return words[0];
```

In other words, the returned pointer points to the first string, namely `first`.
Then, the loop prints each element (character) in turn

```
f
i
r
s
```

---

To solve this, you must return the whole array, namely a pointer to `words`. This would change the signature and the return to

```
char **stringsplit(char msg[])
{
    // ...

    return words;
}
```

But this won't work either, because now `stringsplit` returns a pointer to a local variable.

---

There are a few ways to resolve this

- make `words` static, e.g.

  ```
  static char *words[4];
  ```
- or use dynamic memory allocation

  ```
  char **words = malloc(4 * sizeof(char*));
  ```
- or pass the words array into stringsplit

  ```
  char **stringsplit(char msg[], char **words)
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```

  and then in setup()

  ```
  char *words[4];
  char **p1 = stringsplit(msg, words);
  ```

Each method has its pros and cons. In this small Arduino example (I'm no expert though), I would prefer the static variant, because it's quick and easy (some will say dirty ;-), even though the last method is the cleanest.

---

Looking at @Furkan's hint, doing the print inline seems the best solution. This also allows easily any number of sub-strings

```
char *p;
char dauphay[] = ",";
p = strtok(msg, dauphay);
while (p) {
    Serial.println(p);
    p = strtok(NULL, dauphay);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much,  can you help me to fix this problem ?

Comment: @nghihoang2207 can you try to change condition i<4 to i<23. And if you want to see output on same line(I mean, not line by line). You have to remove `ln` from `Serial.println(p1[i])` . I think it will work if I got you right.

Comment: @Furkan Thank you but I want to split the input (MSG) to many array like words[1], words[2]...., so your solution can not help me to split my input, do you have other solution ?

Comment: Take a look here I hope it works. http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/1237